# PHP = Envia Mensagem + Mensagem Agradecimento + (botão) ou refresh

Tags: script, phpmailer, button, echo

Boas, 
Sou bicão e fico mexendo no meu site gostaria da ajuda de vc´s:

Após o cliente enviar mensagem aparecia tela branca com mensagem de agradecimento. Corrigi para retornar ao site mas a mensagem sumiu.

```
echo   "$nome,  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!";

header("Location: http://www.xxxxx.com.br");
```

---

Gostaria de colocar um `echo` ou `script` (*Já estou me familiarizando com os termos rs rs*) de agradecimento e a página retornar ao site sozinho.

Já **tentei** algumas coisas copiadas e adaptadas da internet

```
(<script language="JavaScript" charset="utf-8">alert("$nome,  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!")</script>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='4; URL= http://www.xxxx.com.br '>)
```

mas não funcionou

**Tentei**

```
<script> alert(  "$nome,  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!)"; </script>”
header("Location: http://www.xxxxx.com.br");
```

Não funcionou

**Tentei**

```
echo “<script language="JavaScript" charset="utf-8">alert("$nome,  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!")</script>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='4; URL= http://www.xxxxx.com.br '>
```

Não funcionou

[image: Imagem mostrando as tentativas]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, com a seguinte função

```
(<script language="JavaScript" charset="utf-8">alert("$nome,  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!")</script><meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='4;URL=http://www.xxxx.com.br'>)
```

Você não consegue printar o nome da pessoa por a variável "$nome" esta com a sintaxe de PHP, o que você poderia fazer é criar uma variável em JavaScript e atribuir a essa função dessa maneira

```
<script type="text/javascript>
let nome = nome enviado pelo usuário
alert(nome+',  Email enviado. Breve entraremos em Contato!');
window.location="http://google.com.br/";
</script>
```

Comment: Olímpio,  Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não conseguir entender muito bem seu código, mas acho que entendi seu objetivo.

Primeiramente tome cuidado com esse carácter **`“`** ele é não cria string como esse aqui `"`, isso ira gerar um erro o que pode fazer você levar um tempo ate descobrir que era esse carácter.

Agora vamos ao problema, pelo que eu entendi você quer que o usuário volte para uma determinada pagina após algum tempo, para o usuário ver a mensagem de e-mail enviado.

Esse código PHP não deve funcionar para seu caso:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

O código acima envia um **header** indicando para o browser que ele deve ir para outro link, então o usuário não chega a ver o HTML.

Se você quiser fazer isso via **header** você pode utilizar o [**Refresh**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20878550/2456894) adicionando **url=** como no exemplo abaixo:

```
/// 10 indica o tempo em segundos
header("Refresh: 10; url=http://minhapagina.com");

/// Agora se eu não estou enganado você tem que
/// colocar esse código antes de escrever algo
/// na página, ou seja, antes do seu echo.
/// Caso contrário acho que ele gera um notice ou warning.
```

Você também pode fazer isso via javascript, utilizando o [`setTimout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) para aguardar um tempo e o [`location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) para redirecionar o usuário, como mostrado abaixo.

```js
/// O número 10000 esta em milisegundos e indica o 
/// tempo que deve esperar para chamar a função
setTimeout( function(){
    location.href = "http://minhapagina.com";
}, 10000 );
```

Agora como percebo que você esta escrevendo esse codigo dentro da area de codigo PHP ou seja dentro das [tags PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) `<?php ?>` ou `<? ?>`, abaixo esta o código gerado com `echo`

```php
echo "<script>";
echo "setTimeout( function(){";
echo "location.href = \"http://minhapagina.com\";";
echo "}, 10000 );";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: essa dica do refresh combinada com o que eu já tinha foi PERFEITA.

header("Refresh: 10; url=http://minhapagina.com");

Obrigadaço, irmão.